# Ubuntu 16.04 consumes lot of power during sleep mode

Tags: 16.04, suspend

When I turn my laptop into suspend mode it consumes 1/3 rd of the power it consumes when it is on, whereas it should just lose very little power. One symptom I know is that even in sleep mode, the USB port gets the power. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should have at least added what laptop are you talking about. For example I was searching for a similar problem with hybrid NVidia graphics, do you have it? On 16.04 I had this problem only with `prime-select nvidia` but after upgrading to 18.04 I'm getting it all the time.

Comment: For 18.04 there is a fresh update, published just 2 hours ago in `bionic-proposed` https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1778011